# Does google index its search result page?

Tags: google, search-engines, google-search, seo

Does google index its search result page?

assuming, google as a website, search results text as a content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not index their own search result pages.

Comment: Any idea or your thoughts on that as to why they do not index their own pages, apart from this obvious reasons - too many pages, they do not require indexing as they are the king themselves. ---Thank you John for answering the question.

Comment: @jeet Why would they want to return search results in their search results? It would help no-one.

Comment: @jeet Your initial question was "Does google index its _search results_ page?". Which would be crazy if they did, so "no". However, your comment asks a different question, "Do [they] index their own pages?". Google controls many sites and many pages, not just the search results, so I guess it is quite possible "they index their own pages"!?

Answer (score 6):

If you look at [google's own robots.txt](http://www.google.com/robots.txt) file you will find the line:

```
Disallow: /search
```

So google does not index it's own search results.

Blogger and Youtube are both owned by google and are indexed. So yes, google does index it's own pages - but not it's search result pages.

[Yahoo's robots.txt](http://search.yahoo.com/robots.txt) for it's search pages has a similar line as does [Bing's robots.txt](http://www.bing.com/robots.txt)